# Можете помочь, мне нужно передать аргументы через argparse

Tags: python, argparse

Мне надо передать несколько аргументов: delay, id, token через argparse следующим образом `python C:\Script.py -d 0.2 -i 4554053 -t "DHFKJDFHGKJH"`

Код:

```
import telebot
import time
import pyautogui
import argparse

delay_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The delay')
delay_parser.add_argument("-d", "--delay", help="The delay in minutes", type=float)

id_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The id')
id_parser.add_argument("-i", "--id", help="The id where the bot will send screenshots", type=str)

token_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='The token')
token_parser.add_argument("-p", "--token", help="Thet telegram bot token", type=str)

delay = delay_parser.parse_args()
id_ = id_parser.parse_args()
token_ = token_parser.parse_args()

minutes = delay
id = id_
token = token_


def get():
    ScreenShot = pyautogui.screenshot()

    return ScreenShot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

while True:
    screen = get()
    print("Successfully saved screenshot")

    bot.send_photo(id, screen)
    print("Successfully sended")

    time.sleep(60 * minutes)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: покажите код, напишите, с какой проблемой вы столкнулись

Comment: Документацию по argparse уже прочитали? С какими трудностями столкнулись?

Comment: Почитайте документацию повнимательнее, ArgumentParser должен быть ровно один для всех опций

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсер нужен один. И у него указываются аргументы.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My program')
parser.add_argument("-d", "--delay", help="The delay in minutes", type=float)
parser.add_argument("-i", "--id"   , help="The id to where the bot will send screenshots", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", "--token", help="The telegram bot token", type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.delay, args.id, args.token)
```